# Question on weightlessness

Tags: acceleration

An astronaut in an artificial satellite of the earth feels weightlessness. Do they feel weightlessness on the moon too? Why?

An astronaut in all artificial satellite feels weightlessness due to the zero reaction force. But I couldn't get the reason for the second question (weightlessness on moon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astronauts do not feel weightless on the Moon where the gravitational field strength is one sixth of that on the Earth.
They feel "lighter" in spite of the heavy suits that they have to wear.
A spring balance would give a reading for the weight of an astronaut on the Moon which was one sixth of that on the Earth.

An astronaut in orbit feels weightless and shows a reading on zero on a spring balance because the astronaut, the spring balance and the space craft are all accelerating at exactly the same rate whilst orbiting the Earth.